# Scraping using BeautifulSoup, value is not clean

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a nutrient tag (http://smartlabel.generalmills.com/41196891218). and I'm having a hard time getting a clean gram value for each category.

For example, this is how it comes out for fat
('fat': '\n                                    1 g\n                                ',)\

Any way to get something like this("fat": 1g)?

I just started learning bs4 yesterday, any help will be appreciated!.

My code is

```py
def minenutrition1(link):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(link)
    # noticed there is an ad here, sleep til page fully loaded.
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    driver.quit()
    calories=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"header2"})[0].text
    fat=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[0].text
    satfat=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[1].text
    cholesterol=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[3].text
    sodium=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[4].text
    carb=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[5].text
    Total_sugar=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[7].text
    protein=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[9].text
    name = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'product-header-name header1'})[0].text
    upc=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"upc sub-header"})
    upc=upc[0].text
```

Comment: how about `"\n 1 g\n ".strip()` ? it gives `"1 g"`. So use `...[0].text.strip()`

Comment: BTW: `BS` has also `get_text(strip=True)`

Comment: BTW to get first element you can use `find()` instead of `find_all()[0]`

Comment: You could use once `items = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})` and later `fat  = items[0].text` and `satfat = items[1].text` , etc.

Answer (score 0):

You get normal string `"\n 1 g\n "` so you can use string functions to clean/change it.

Using `"\n 1 g\n ".strip()` you can get `"1 g"`

So you can add `.strip()` at the end of this line

```
fat = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[0].text.strip()
```

or do it later

```
fat = fat.strip()
```

`BS` has also function `.get_text(strip=True)` which you can use instead of `.text`

```
fat = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"gram-value"})[0].get_text(strip=True)
```

---

Minimal working code.

I display `fat` with `> <` to see if there are spaces, tabs, enters (new lines).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'http://smartlabel.generalmills.com/41196891218'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# noticed there is an ad here, sleep til page fully loaded.
time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()

items = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "gram-value"})

fat = items[0].text
print('>{}<'.format(fat))

fat = items[0].text.strip()
print('>{}<'.format(fat))

fat = items[0].get_text(strip=True)
print('>{}<'.format(fat))
```

Result:

```
>
                                    1 g
                                <
>1 g<
>1 g<
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would not use Selenium. Not that you can't, but the site is static, and you can get the html source straight away with `requests`. So this is a little bit of a stretch since you are beginning with BeautifulSoup, but if you open Dev Tools (Ctrl-Shift-I) and reload the page, you will notice the requests made in the right panel under Network -> XHR. There is a requeset to GetNutritionalDetails.

Withibn there, you'll see the request url, and the the requests headers, and at the bottom the payload. You will also see it's a `POST` request (usually you'll use `GET`.

[image]

The data is within a list (`<li>` tags). So it's not just a mater of getting all those tags, then iterate through each of those, to pull out the other data.

You can append that data into a list, and then that list into a table/dataframe with pandas.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://smartlabel.generalmills.com/GTIN/GetNutritionalDetails'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'id': '41196891218',
'servingSize': 'AS PACKAGED'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
listItems = soup.find_all('li')

labels = []
gramValues = []
percValues = []

for each in listItems:
    label = each.find('label').text.strip()
    if label == 'Includes':
        label += ' Added Sugar'
    gram = each.find('span', {'class':'gram-value'}).text.strip()
    if each.find('span', {'class':'dv-result'}):
        perc = each.find('span', {'class':'dv-result'}).text.strip()
    else:
        perc = ''

    labels.append(label)
    gramValues.append(gram)
    percValues.append(perc)


df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Label':labels,
        'Grams':gramValues,
        'Percent':percValues})
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                   Label   Grams Percent
0              Total Fat     1 g     1 %
1          Saturated Fat     0 g     0 %
2              Trans Fat     0 g        
3            Cholesterol    0 mg     0 %
4                 Sodium  810 mg    35 %
5     Total Carbohydrate    17 g     6 %
6          Dietary Fiber     2 g     6 %
7            Total Sugar     2 g        
8   Includes Added Sugar     2 g     3 %
9                Protein     4 g        
10             Vitamin D    0 ?g     0 %
11               Calcium   60 mg     4 %
12                  Iron  1.2 mg     6 %
13             Potassium    0 mg     0 %
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. I read from somewhere that If the source is different than the inspect element, then the page is dynamic, I guess not. Can this be done with multiple pages without typing in each payload?

Comment: well the payload will be what you send to get a certain request. Looks like it's the ID that corresponds to the item. If you can get that ID returned in the search, then you could dynamically feed that in to get the nutritional values